# Review counts by review queue

Tags: feature-request

I have a suggestion...

When I go to the activity section of my profile to view my total review count, it would be nice to see review counts aggregated by review queue (e.g. Triage - 12 reviews, First Posts - 100 reviews, etc.).  This would tie directly to the corresponding badges earned for each review queue.

As it stands now, I have no idea how far along I am towards the next badge for each review queue.

Comment: You can view your badge progress by hovering over the progress bar visible in each of the review queues.

Comment: @animuson Got it.  But what's interesting is that often times the total number of reviews (reported under activity->review in the user profile) is not equal to the sum of the total reviews for each queue.  Even after waiting a while to see if it's some sort of back-end latency, the problem persists.

Comment: Your activity does not list posts which have been deleted since you reviewed them, though they still count towards your review totals for the badges.

Comment: @animuson Ah, got it.  Thank you.